# Amplify GraphQL subscriptions returns null

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I have an app build an app using Amplify and graphQL.

I have started using this workshop: https://amplify-workshop.go-aws.com/60_managing_photos/40_upload_photos_consolidated.html

It worked fine at first. I have started to modify it and now when I upload a new picture, the subscription returns null.
If I look in the database, I see the row created.
If I refresh the page, everything works fine, no errors.
I don't understand why I get null

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription
    async function setupSubscription() {
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      subscription = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreatePhoto, {owner: user.username})).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          console.log('subscriptions.data=',data)

          const photo = data.value.data.onCreatePhoto
          if (photo.albumId !== props.id) return
            setPhotos(p => p.concat([photo]))
        }
      })
    }
    setupSubscription()

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [props.id])
```

The result of `console.log('subscriptions.data=',data)` is

```
subscriptions.onCreatePhoto= null
```

I don't know where to look.

What could be the reason for receiving null on a subscription ?

How to debug it ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I tried to test the creation and the subscription on the AWS Console.
And I have seen some errors in the output of my subscription:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'AWSDateTime' within parent 'Photo' (/onCreatePhoto/createdAt)",
      "path": [
        "onCreatePhoto",
        "createdAt"
      ]
```

I have found this issue https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4613

I have deleted the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` from my subscription query and I don't have any errors and I have the right response after creating a photo.

The problem is that my subscription file is auto generated by amplify, so I don't know how to solve it for ever, not being forced to modify each time amplify will re generate it.

Comment: I just ran into this too.  I get the event, but the `onCreateXXX` is null and I've had to similarly trace out event.value.errors to see it.   Kinda odd since its generated code, but I definitely see the response is `null`.

Comment: I now believe part of my problem was the @auth section of my schema.  Now I'm at least getting the global and secondary index but none of my other fields.

Comment: My issue was related to the mutation not returning back all fields.  I found if I only returned id, the subscription suffered too.  That was not clear in the docs but now mine is working correctly.